# Removing class of singular row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a row in a HTML table, I want to remove the `highlightedRow` class from the previously clicked row, and add it to the new one.

```
$(function () {
    $("table tr").click(function (e) {
        //remove class 
        var dataTable = $("#TemplateData");
        dataTable.removeClass("highlightedRow");

        //add class
        var dTable = $(this);
        dTable.addClass("highlightedRow");
        g_previouslyClickedRow = $(this).index()
}
```

Problem is:

```
var dTable = $(this);
dTable.addClass("highlightedRow");
```

is getting the row element while:

```
var dataTable = $("#TemplateData");
dataTable.removeClass("highlightedRow");
```

is getting the table element.
How can I use the table element and the `previouslySelectedRow` value?

```
g_previouslyClickedRow = $(this).index()
```

to get the row element?

Comment: Adding html would help to find out the solution to the problem described.

Comment: if you have only one `"highlightedRow"` just do `$('.highlightedRow').removeClass("highlightedRow");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target proper `element` to `removeClass`

```
$("table tr").click(function (e) {
     //remove class 
      $('.highlightedRow').removeClass('highlightedRow');
     //add class
     $(this).addClass("highlightedRow");
}
```

When you say :

```
var dataTable = $("#TemplateData");
//dataTable will have reference to your table if #TemplateData is the id of your table
dataTable.removeClass("highlightedRow");
//the above line will just remove class from table as you have stored reference of your table
//in dataTable
```

and when you say:

```
var dTable = $(this);
//$(this) will be referring to current element context inside click
dTable.addClass("highlightedRow");
//and thus the clicked element, whose reference is stored in dTable, will get the class 
//highlightedRow.
```

Comment: Anytime @John.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do Simply

```
 $(".highlightedRow").removeClass("highlightedRow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr").click(function (e) {
     g_previouslyClickedRow = $('.highlightedRow').index();
     //remove class 
      $('.highlightedRow').removeClass("highlightedRow");

     //add class
     $(this).addClass("highlightedRow");
}
```

Comment: Can you add a short explanation to your code sample?